# Celery hangs when -C is greater than 1

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, celery

I'm running a rabbitmq server and a default Celery task. I'm trying to get it to run on multiple cores - whenever I run `celery -A tasks worker -C 1` the process runs quickly, but if I run `celery -A tasks worker -C X` where `x > 1`, jobs sporadically get processed when I exit and create a new celery instance.

My task is just to insert into a MySQL instance.

My physical machine has 12 cores, and I'm running this on DigitalOcean.

Does anyone know why this is happening? It appears to be task agnostic. Thanks!

Comment: That's too bad. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: @MarcB does that clarify my question?

Comment: Hi can you please post some log lines ?